# Running JUnit tests on eclipse-test-plugins from maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit, rcp

I have a maven3 multi-module RCP eclipse project. I want to run JUnit tests from maven. The modules that have JUnit tests are eclipse-plugins. I've tried to run them using `Tycho Surefire Plugin` by adding this at pom file:

```
    <packaging>eclipse-test-plugin</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/test</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
        <artifactId>tycho-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.24.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <includes>
              <include>**/*Test.java</include>
          </includes>
          <useUIHarness>false</useUIHarness>
          <providerHint>junit4</providerHint>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

With `mvn test` the tests are not triggered. Only the classes are compiled.
With `mvn verify` I get the following error:

> -------------------------------------------------------  T E S T S
>   ------------------------------------------------------- An error has occurred. See the log file
>   E:\Git\EF8_Toolcenter_repository_custom\de.audi.eftc.platform.contact\target\work\data.metadata.log.
>
> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-surefire-plugin:0.24.0:test (default-test) on
>   project xxxx.contact: An unexpected error occured while launching the
>   test runtime (return code 13). See log for details. -> [Help 1]

The log contains:

> !SESSION 2019-03-05 11:31:23.457
>   ----------------------------------------------- eclipse.buildId=unknown java.version=1.8.0_191 java.vendor=Oracle
>   Corporation BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32,
>   NL=en_US Framework arguments:  -application
>   org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.headlesstest -testproperties
>   xxxx\target\surefire.properties
>   Command-line arguments:  -data
>   xxxx\target\work\data
>   -application org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.headlesstest -testproperties 
>   xxxx\target\surefire.properties
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.junit4 2 0 2019-03-05 11:31:24.892
>   !MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.junit4
>   [134]   Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: junit.framework;
>   version="3.0.0"   Unresolved requirement: Import-Package:
>   junit.framework; version="3.0.0"
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2019-03-05 11:31:24.893 !MESSAGE
>   Application error !STACK 1
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.util.SurefireReflectionException:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider   at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.loadClass(ReflectionUtils.java:251)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.instantiateOneArg(ReflectionUtils.java:128)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireReflector.instantiateProvider(SurefireReflector.java:235)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.createProvider(ProviderFactory.java:113)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:78)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.OsgiSurefireBooter.run(OsgiSurefireBooter.java:91)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.HeadlessTestApplication.run(HeadlessTestApplication.java:21)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(EclipseAppContainer.java:587)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:656)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:592)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1498)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1471) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider   at
>   org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.osgibooter.CombinedClassLoader.findClass(CombinedClassLoader.java:37)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.loadClass(ReflectionUtils.java:243)
>     ... 24 more

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: See [this Eclipse Tycho tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html#executing-plug-in-unit-tests-with-tycho) with the [example project](https://github.com/vogellacompany/tycho-example/tree/master/tests).

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out what was the problem. I had to put to dependencies in `MANIFEST.MF` also the `org.junit`.